# Why is the JS constructor function create functions from strings?

Tags: javascript, constructor, javascript-objects

As I understand the `.constructor` value is a `Function()` for classes.

In short, why constructor attribute is a `Function` and whta the rational about it?

Example:
`Set.constructor -> Function()`

Answer (score 1):

Classes are (very) special kinds of functions; `Set` inherits from `Function.prototype`.

`Function.prototype` has a `constructor` property - that's what `Set.constructor` refers to. (`Set` does not have an own `constructor` property - it's only inherited.)

The constructor of `Function.prototype` is what you can call to create a Function instance - which, in this special case, is just `Function`.

```js
console.log(Set.constructor === Function);
```

So

```
Set.constructor('alert(1);')
```

is equivalent to

```
Function('alert(1);')
```

Comment: I was initially confused by this, but now it’s very obvious to me. I’ll provide an alternative way of explaining this: The thing that creates new `Set` objects sits at `Set.prototype.constructor` which of course is just `Set` itself. `Set.prototype` is the object that hosts all the methods and properties that all `Set` objects have in common and the `constructor` property within it just points back to `Set` itself. (1 / 2)

Comment: (2 / 2) `Set.constructor`, however would be a _static_ property of `Set`. Since this would just be an arbitrary property with no special meaning, it doesn’t exist, at least not as an own property; but it is inherited! It’s inherited from some kind of object with methods and properties that all _functions_ (which classes are a “(very) special” kind of) have in common. Well, that object would be `Function.prototype`, of course! And yes, that’s `Function.prototype.constructor`, indeed, which, by the same reasoning as with `Set.prototype.constructor`, _is_ `Function`.